# Ruby on Rails: Routing Error ONLY when typing into browser, but works when clicking on a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If' I'm typing the URL into the browser, I get a Routing Error, but if I'm clicking a link to that URL, it works. Why is it like this?

```
  devise_for :user, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
    get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
    post 'signup/:invitation_token' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration 
    get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session 
    post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session 
    delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

For example, If I type localhost:3000/signout into the browser, I'll get the error. But if there's a link

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

It will work. Same thing goes with the other customized routes.

Comment: When you hover over the "logout" link (or if you view the HTML source), what path does it provide?

Comment: @mbratch i get `localhost:3000/signout`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Did any of the answers below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [Devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), you'll see that the various Devise controller actions are invoked by various HTTP requests.

For instance, the new `sign_in` method is a `GET` request:

```
# GET /resource/sign_in
```

But the actual **creation** of a new user session is a `POST` request:

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
```

And the `sign_out` method is a `DELETE` request:

```
# DELETE /resource/sign_out
```

Of those three request types (`GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE`), only `GET` requests can be made simply by typing the URL into your browser – the other two types require specific HTTP headers are typically set either in forms, links, or the like.

The precise type of request that must be made to access each Devise controller method is available as inline documentation in [the source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)... I recommend you have a look.

Comment: would it be good if instead of `delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session` I'll do `get 'signout' => ... `?

Comment: It is __not__ recommended to override `delete` with `get` in this situation. `devise/sessions#destroy` is a _destructive_ action, and as such, it's appropriate to request it as a `delete` request. If you're destroying anything — session data included — you should be requesting the destructive action via `delete`.

Comment: Did this question help resolve your question? If so, would you kindly consider accepting/voting it up?

Comment: What do you suggest I should do if I want to be able to type in signout in my url and it will do so?

Comment: If you absolutely must be able to signout via GET, then make your route a get request as you've mentioned. However, you will risk accidental sign outs as [this commenter on Github](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/issues/4#issuecomment-1540335) has thoroughly articulated. Another good reason to avoid using `GET` requests to change the state of the server is that the author of Devise specifically changed `sign_out` from `GET` to `DELETE`: [Github commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/adb127bb3e3b334cba903db2c21710e8c41c2b40)

Comment: Given this additional info, do you feel that this answer has provided enough insight to warrant being accepted as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The routing error is present when you manually enter the URL because web browsers send GET requests by default. Your link example there is creating a DELETE request, as per `:method => :delete`. So the verb (GET vs DELETE vs PATCH vs POST) has to match the route as well. You can see this explained for your app specifically by running `rake routes`. You'll see the urls along with the request type/verb.

If you'd like to make a similar DELETE request you can look into doing so with curl: http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/

Comment: Yeah, but I get the error not only from logout, but also other routes like signup

Comment: Can you show the relevant output from `rake routes`? The answer has to be in there.

Comment: This is my signout rake route    `destroy_user_session DELETE /signout(.:format)     devise/sessions#destroy`